# Episerver CMS text editor disabled for non-english languagues

Tags: asp.net, episerver, episerver-6

I have an Episerver CMS 6 R2 site that has multiple languages. 
For some reason I cannot edit pages that are not English.

In the screenshot below I'm trying to translate a page into Japanese, but after changing the Page View drop list from English to Japanese, the editor controls become greyed out and disabled. In the English version it is enabled.

I'm logged in as an administrator and it appears I have right access levels in the 'Manage Website Languages'  area of the admin.

Do you have any idea why I can edit Japanese content?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might need to add the `[CultureSpecific]` attribute to your property

Comment: This sounds like the correct answer. Non-localizable properties are only editable on the **master language** version, which appears to be English in your case.